# Bought a 1U server, now can't find rails

Tags: hardware, rackmount

I bought a 1U server used on eBay (a Supermicro motherboard, but branded "Asempra"), and I also bought a set of "Supermicro" rails, but unfortunately the rails didn't fit the server.

The side of the server looks like: http://hphotos-snc3.fbcdn.net/hs441.snc3/25351_686753868807_122602581_40791051_5292592_n.jpg

Can you tell me where I can find rails for this machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the server has a brand of a company that evidently doesn't make servers any more, googling the first part of the serial number on the SuperMicro web site found a family of servers, all of which use the same model number of rail kit.  Evidently this one uses a CSE-PT51 rail kit.
http://www.ewiz.com/newg/C/A/-/CA-PT51L/CA-PT51L_LG.GIF
Note the black plastic thing in the pieces on the left, and how they match the black plastic thing on my computer.

Thanks for the shelf suggestions, everybody.

Answer (score 2):

You could always just get a shelf, and set it on top of the shelf.  The rails where lost for a server, and in trying to find the replacement rails I found that a shelf was less expensive.  A shelf does waste a little space in your rack, but in my case this wasn't really an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In that picture, that's the server side of the rail, right?  We can't actually see how it's attached to the server.

Worst case, get one of the sets of rails that attaches to the rack and just has little flanges that stick out and the server sits on top of those.  This is one type, we have a couple sets we got from HP that have smaller flanges:

http://www.server-rack-online.com/universal-server-rack-rails.html

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, racksolutions.com has a few universal kits that fit just about anything I throw at them.  No slides, but better than buying a shelf.